# Unable to read returned Javascript object from a different script file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I have two simple JavaScript page. One holds the function that returns the object. The other read the returned object.

Unfortunately I am unable to read the returned object.

main.js

```
var userObj = getUserInfo('2');
console.log(userObj); //undefined
console.log(userObj.name); //undefined
```

globals.js

```
function getUserInfo(mapID){
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: user_url,
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                handleError404("Error 404 at getUserInfo();")
            },
            500: function () {
                handleError500("Error 500 at getUserInfo();")
            },
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var obj = {
                name: data.name,
                age: data.age,
                weight: data.weight
            }
            console.log(obj); //{name:"Kanye West", age:23, weight:"450lbs"}
            return obj;
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, If I was to output the object in the function itself, I see the result. But not if I call it from the main.js page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ignore this, for some reason I can't delete this comment.

Comment: Sorry I'd not properly looked at your code before commenting. For some reason the delete comment button doesn't want to do anything.

Comment: The ajax call is asynchronous. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call for ways to deal with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't return anything from `getUserInfo` so you shouldn't expect anything from it.

You are only returning something in the success callback function. That is is run asynchronously. It doesn't return anything for `getUserInfo`.

If you want to make your ajax call a separate function you can make it return a promise from `$.ajax` instead of using a `success` callback.

```
function getUserInfo(mapID){
    return $.ajax({
        url: user_url,
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                handleError404("Error 404 at getUserInfo();")
            },
            500: function () {
                handleError500("Error 500 at getUserInfo();")
            },
        }
    });
}
```

then in main.js

```
var promise = getUserInfo('2');
promise.done(function(userObj) {
  console.log(userObj);
  console.log(userObj.name);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean I don't? return obj; is there to return it?

Comment: let me expand my answer

Comment: Thank you for the sample and explanation! Works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything.

The `success` callback function in the `$.ajax()` call is invoked asynchronously, meaning it is executed after the HTTP request is done.

Also, it is a different `function` than `getUserInfo`. At this point you are just **returning a value for the `success` function**.

I will suggest using another function that will process whatever you receive in the success call. SO in your successs call you get to add a line like `handleObject(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass as function argument a **callback** or a **promise**.

Reason is simple. You are calling an ajax call, which will be finished after your function will end it's call. That is why you need to add a callback/promise.

```
function getUserInfo(mapID, callback){
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: user_url,
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                handleError404("Error 404 at getUserInfo();")
            },
            500: function () {
                handleError500("Error 500 at getUserInfo();")
            },
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var obj = {
                name: data.name,
                age: data.age,
                weight: data.weight
            }
            callback(obj);
        }
    });
}
```

In order to execute your function you simply call:

```
getUserInfo(manId, function(object){
   console.log('AJAX results');
});
```